# How to handle popovers using Selenium Webdriver + Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

Here is the situation - 
On the website that I am testing, the page source changes dynamically i.e. when I move my mouse over an element I see a popover and it has DOM structure and all. I want to capture the DOM elements in the popover.

I am using webdriver with python. It works well when I use IDLE because the popover stays on the webpage awhile and I can capture the DOM structure. However, when I try to execute that in a script, the popover merely flashes on the screen and I cannot capture the DOM structure.

I have tried using WebDriverWait, Actions API etc. But nothing is working. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Actions to hover the mouse over the element. The straight-forward approach is something like this (sorry the code is in C#):

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("something")); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();

//get the DOM structure
```

Important is to not forget the `Perform()` call. If this doesn't work (which sometimes it just doesn't), **replace `MoveToElement` with `ClickAndHold`**. Usually this keeps things like mouseover pop ups open indefinitely.